# Sort range based on a column using a google sheets API in Java

Tags: java, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have my Java code working fine with retrieving and updating data to my Google Sheets spreadsheet.

I am trying to sort the data after updating, and getting a 500 Internal Server Error and was wondering what I am sending wrong. I am trying to ASCENDING sort Range "E1:I1000"

Here is my code:

```
        Sheets sheetsService = GoogleAuthorizeUtil.getSheetsService("worktest");
    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest busReq = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    SortRangeRequest srr = new SortRangeRequest();
    GridRange gr = new GridRange();
    SortSpec ss = new SortSpec();
    Request req = new Request();
    
    gr.setSheetId(0);
    gr.setStartRowIndex(1);
    gr.setEndRowIndex(1000);
    gr.setStartColumnIndex(5);
    gr.setEndColumnIndex(10);
    
    srr.setRange(gr);
    
    ss.setSortOrder("ASCENDING");
    ss.setDimensionIndex(1);
    
    srr.setSortSpecs(Arrays.asList(ss));
    
    req.setSortRange(srr);
    
    busReq.setRequests(Arrays.asList(req));
    
    sheetsService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(googleID, busReq).execute();
```

Is there anything wrong in how I am trying to sort this?

Comment: To clarify, in the provided code, if you comment out `ss.setSortOrder` and `ss.setDimensionIndex`, it works properly?  You can check here for the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters.

Comment: I did comment out the ss portion, and it continues but doesn't look to be sorting my data.

Comment: Do you have the columns based-zero indexed?  I believe everything should be zero-based.  At the very least, the dimension index = 1 refers to the second column of your data according to the guide.

Comment: Yes, I have double checked and they are all zero based. I had merged rows in column A, but have removed it and still getitng 500 error. My dimension is correct because in this instance I do want to sort on the 2nd column of my range.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*You are trying to sort columns `E:I` by column `B` - this is not possible!*

#### More Information:

In your code, you are setting the `dimensionIndex` for which to sort the data by, to the value of `1`. This isn't the second column of the data you want to sort, but the second column ***of your whole spreadsheet***.

This isn't clear from the [SortSpec](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#sortspec) documentation, but can be inferred from the example provided by Google in the [Data Operations documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data#sort_a_range_with_multiple_sorting_specifications)

#### Code Fix:

All you need to do to sort this is change the value passed to `setDimensionIndex`:

```java
ss.setDimensionIndex(1)
```

change to:

```java
ss.setDimensionIndex(6)
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Data Operations | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data)
- [Sheets API | Google Developers - SortSpec](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#sortspec)